# Outputting arrays with PSObject; Limitted to 4 columns

Tags: powershell, psobject

A snippet of my code:

```
$ipaddress = '127.0.0.1'
$port = 135,137,138,139,443,445   

for($i=0; $i -lt $port.length; $i++)
{

$out = new-object psobject

$out | add-member noteproperty Host $ipaddress
$out | add-member noteproperty Port $port[$i]
$out | add-member noteproperty Isopen $isopen[$i]
$out | add-member noteproperty Desc "Desc"
$out | add-member noteproperty Notes $Notes[$i]
$out | add-member noteproperty Issue $issue[$i]


Write-Output $out 

 }
```

What I'm trying to do is print out the results of my port scanner into a nice table.
This works fine when there's 4 or less columns:

[image: ss1]

But Whenever I add more columns, even though there's space on the screen, it converts it into a list:

[image: ss2]

When I try to append "Format-Table" to it, it writes out the headers each time:

```
Write-Output $out | Format-Table
```

[image: SS3]

If I copy the line `"Write-Output $out"` outside the loop, it only prints out the last member. Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've found, PowerShell formats your output in a table by default, but opts for list view when the objects being formatted have more than 4 visible members.

You can override this by explicitly invoking your preferred `Format-*` command. Simply "collect" all the output objects in an variable then explicitly pipe them to `Format-Table`:

```bsh
$ipaddress = '127.0.0.1'
$port = 135,137,138,139,443,445   

$objects = for($i=0; $i -lt $port.length; $i++)
{

    $out = new-object psobject

    $out | add-member noteproperty Host $ipaddress
    $out | add-member noteproperty Port $port[$i]
    $out | add-member noteproperty Isopen $isopen[$i]
    $out | add-member noteproperty Desc "Desc"
    $out | add-member noteproperty Notes $Notes[$i]
    $out | add-member noteproperty Issue $issue[$i]

    Write-Output $out
}

$objects |Format-Table
```

---

Unless you're running your code on PowerShell 2.0, I'd suggest using the 3.0 `[pscustomobject]` syntax for creating your object (and perhaps turn the whole thing into a function):

```bsh
function Get-PortStatus
{
  param(
    [string]$IPAddress = '127.0.0.1',
    [intp[]]$Port = 135,137,138,139,443,445
  )

  # populate $isopen, $notes, $issue etc. here ...

  for($i=0; $i -lt $port.length; $i++)
  {
    # Write-Output is implied when the new object isn't assigned to anything
    [pscustomobject]@{
      Host   = $ipaddress
      Port   = $port[$i]
      IsOpen = $isopen[$i]
      Desc   = "Desc"
      Notes  = $Notes[$i]
      Issue  = $issue[$i]
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
PS C:\Users\Gabrielius> Get-PortStatus -IPAddress '10.0.0.10' -Port 80,443 |Format-Table
```

Comment: Simple and brilliant, thank you. Do you know why there's a limit of 4? Curious why exactly that number

Comment: The behavior is there because the more columns you have, the chance that they'll spill beyond the screen buffer and hide output is higher - 4 is just an arbitrary decision someone had to make :)

Comment: @Gabrielius Check `$out.PSStandardMembers.DefaultDisplayPropertySet`, see [Using DefaultPropertySet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-7#using-defaultpropertyset-the-long-way).

Comment: @JosefZ That only works well if you _don't_ want 4+ properties displayed - with a display set containing 5 or more properties it'll still default to list view

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own type and table view in a .format.ps1xml file, if it's worth it to you.  Here's a simple example.  The format is documented at [About Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7)  There's actually format files for all the custom objects in powershell.  This is rather boilerplate.  I wish there were a $numPropsToTable preference variable.

myobject.format.ps1xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Configuration>
  <ViewDefinitions>
    <View>
      <Name>myobject</Name>
      <ViewSelectedBy>
        <TypeName>myobject</TypeName>
      </ViewSelectedBy>
      <TableControl>
        <TableHeaders>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>16</Width>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>16</Width>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>16</Width>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>16</Width>
          </TableColumnHeader>
          <TableColumnHeader>
            <Width>16</Width>
          </TableColumnHeader>
        </TableHeaders>
        <TableRowEntries>
          <TableRowEntry>
            <TableColumnItems>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>Address</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>City</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>State</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
              <TableColumnItem>
                <PropertyName>Zip</PropertyName>
              </TableColumnItem>
            </TableColumnItems>
          </TableRowEntry>
        </TableRowEntries>
      </TableControl>
    </View>
  </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

```
update-formatdata myobject.format.ps1xml
[pscustomobject]@{name='me';address='here';city='la';state='ca';zip=11111
  PSTypeName = 'MyObject'}

Name             Address          City             State            Zip
----             -------          ----             -----            ---
me               here             la               ca               11111
```